# How to send something after done formidable processing?

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I learn to use formidable to process form with code like below.

```
router.post('/add/', function(req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        ...
        res. ???
```

After processing is done, I want to send some message back. I have tried `res.write`, `res.send` and `res.redirect`, none works with error like **cannot set header, write after end etc**.

So what is the right to do it? Thanks.

Comment: `res.send()` works fine no matter how long after you send it (up until the browser times out waiting for the response) as long as you haven't already sent some other response to that particular request.  If you show us the ENTIRE route handler code, we can probably show you where your error is.

Comment: You are right. I found it is due to my bug. Thanks a lot for the help!